# how to find and remove object form a list of python object

Tags: python, if-statement, debugging, boolean, equality

i am new to python. I am a java programmer. I have a list of Object of a class. My intention is to find and remove an object from the list.

**class**

```
class commit:
    def __init__(self, id, message):
        self.id = id
        self.message = message
```

**The code where i am trying to find and delete:**

```
elif command.startswith("git delete"):
        split = command.split();
        deleteID = split[2]; // the id which will be deleted.
        print('deleteID:' + deleteID)
        d1 = {};
        for obj in listCommit:
            print(obj.id)
            if obj.id == deleteID:
                print(obj)
                listCommit.remove(obj);
                d1 = obj;
        # listCommit.remove(d1);
```

I have found that this `if obj.id == deleteID:` is not working.

`listCommit.remove(d1);` this line showing error that object doesn't exit.

So my question is: how can I find and delete an object form the list?

and this `if obj.id == deleteID:` checking is giving false, while it should give true.

Comment: Are `obj.id` and `deleteID` of the same type?

Comment: This is just like Java code mechanically translated into Python; your `commit` class is not necessary, it's just a wrapper for tuples of (id,message). You could the use a list comprehension to remove specific id:  `[(id,msg) for id,msg in commits if msg!= delete_id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the `commit.id` variable is type `int`, whereas the `deleteID` variable is type `str`,
and things like `"5" == 5` will never be `True` in python.

Simply replace the line

```
deleteID = split[2]
```

with

```
deleteID = int(split[2])
```

to convert the data type to be compatible with the `commit.id` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception thrown when the value isn't in the list:

```
try:
    listCommit.remove(d1)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)'s the remove API: